# Changes made to a managed JPA entity after it has been persisted are not saved on commit

Tags: hibernate, jpa

If I instance a new entity and persist it then modify some of the attributes or relationships those changes are not saved to the database when the transaction is committed.  I became aware of this when a @NotNull column was set after the persist and the subsequent commit failed.  In cases where related entities are in play and the relationships are annotated with Cascade.PERSIST the timing of the persist is not always obvious.

I was able to verify this with a very simple test using an entity that had a @NotNull attribute named Version.

```
private void testCommit {
    EntityManager em = <Get an entity manager in the usual way>
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    TestEntity testEntity = new TestEntity();
    testEntity.setAttr1(123);

    em.persist(testEntity);

// At this point the entity is visible in the session that backs the entity manager and only has a single attribute set.

    testEntity.setNotNullField(1);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

The commit will fail with a constraint violation because what is sent to the DB does not include the value for "NotNullField".

Rearranging the code so that the setNotNullField is before the persist allows the commit to succeed.

Is there a way to get Hibernate to track changes made to the entity after persist but before the commit ?

Thanks in advance for any help !

Comment: no, that is well-known pain in behind